# How to hide Fultterwave API keys in Android Apps

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, flutterwave

I'm building an android app and currently integrating Flutterwave into my app for payment.
I am adviced NEVER to put my Flutterwave API keys on my app. So how do i hide these keys.
I'm using Retrofit for my network operations.
Thanks i'm a newbie to this.

Comment: You can't hide your Firebase configuration, and it's not even really intended to be "private" information.

Comment: Good day Doug Stevenson, I'm not taking about my Firebase configuration. I'm talking about hiding my Flutterwave API secret key. Thank you.

Comment: Good day Doug Stevenson, I'm not taking about my Firebase configuration. I'm talking about hiding my Flutterwave API secret key. Thank you.

Comment: OK, I will remove all references to Firebase since it's not relelvant here.

Comment: I'm using Firebase for my backend and i thought the answer would relate to Firebase thats why i put the tag there as it is adviced that you hide your API keys on your server.

Comment: The implementation will be basically the same no matter what your backend.